# How to create a Spring Boot consumer for an ActiveMQ queue?

Tags: java, spring-boot, activemq-classic

I am learning about ActiveMQ, and so far I have made a simple Spring Boot producer+consumer application (call it **App1** for the purposes of this question) that communicates with a local instance of ActiveMQ and everything works as expected.

Now I am trying to run a different Spring Boot application (on the same computer but after ensuring **App1** is not running) that has only a consumer (no producer), but when I start up this application, the messages in the queue (that I put using a modified **App1** in which I removed the consumer portion of the application) do not get picked up. In **App1**, as soon as the message was published, the consumer printed out the system.out print statement, but not so in this consumer-only application. Below is my listener component class:

```
package com.demo.listener;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.JmsListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Consumer {

    @JmsListener(destination = "testqueue")
    public void consume(String message) {

        System.out.println("Picked up message: " + message);

    }
}
```

What changes would I need to make in order achieve the desired behavior?

**App1** `application.properties` file:

```
spring.activemq.in-memory=false
spring.activemq.pool.enabled=false
server.port=9000
activemq.broker-url=tcp://localhost:61616
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration
security.basic.enabled=false
management.security.enabled=false
```

**App1** JmsConfig class

```
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;

@Configuration
public class JmsConfig {

    @Value("${activemq.broker-url}")
    private String brokerUrl;

    @Bean
    public Queue queue() {
        return new ActiveMQQueue("testqueue");
    }

    @Bean
    public ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory() {

        ActiveMQConnectionFactory factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        factory.setBrokerURL(brokerUrl);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate() {
        return  new JmsTemplate(activeMQConnectionFactory());
    }

}
```

**App1** Producer class

```
import javax.jms.Queue;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rest/publish")
public class ProducerResource {

    @Autowired
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    @Autowired
    Queue queue;

    @GetMapping("/{message}")
    public String publishMessage(@PathVariable("message") final String message) {

        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(queue, message);

        return "Published successfully";
    }

}
```

**App1** consumer class is the same class I used in the consumer only application (listed above).

Comment: Please post your application.properties file as well, if possible for both apps. And listener configuration class code as well. You have provided too little information to find out the root cause.

Comment: @AmithKumar I have added the App1 properties file. For the second app (consumer only application) that is my only JMS related class and no MQ/JMS settings are present in the properties file.

Comment: If you use Spring-Boot you do not need Configuration bean for simple use cases like yours.

Comment: Note also the activemq url property should be prefixed by spring. like this: `spring.activemq.broker-url=tcp://192.168.1.210:9876`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your consumer app, you do need to add Pool connection factory & JMS message listener factory for your consumer JMStemplate to start receiving messages.

```
@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class ConsumerConfig {

  @Value("${activemqbrokerurl}")
  private String brokerUrl;

  @Bean
  public ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory() {
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
    activeMQConnectionFactory.setBrokerURL(brokerUrl);
    return activeMQConnectionFactory;
  }

  @Bean
  public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory() {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(activeMQConnectionFactory());
    factory.setConcurrency("{#setDesiredConcurrency}");
    return factory;
  }
}
```

> Spring's MessagListenerContainer should be used for message consumption. This provides all the power of MDBs - efficient JMS consumption and pooling of the message listeners - but without requiring a full EJB container.
> You can use the activemq-pool org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory for efficient pooling of the connections and sessions for your collection of consumers, or you can use the Spring JMS org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory to achieve the same effect.

You can read more about it [here](http://activemq.apache.org/spring-support.html)

Comment: This worked, after adding `containerFactory = "jmsListenerContainerFactory"` as a parameter in the `@JmsListener` annotation.

Comment: For enabling the activemq pooling in spring-boot you do not need extra configuration. Just add the properties and the pom dependecy org.messaginghub:pooled-jms. The official doc is here. All beans are defined by default. Use configuration Bean if you need to derive from the default spring-boot configuration.